# Reset form using h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Can I use instead of `<h:commandButton value="Reset" class="link" type="reset" />`

this code to reset form values?

```
<h:commandLink value="Reset" class="link" type="reset" style="margin: 20px;">
   <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

`h:commandLink` will not behave like `h:commandButton` with `type="reset"` because in `h:commandLink` attribute `type` defines content type of the resource designated by this hyperlink (for example `text/ html, image/gif`).

Using this code:

```
<h:commandLink value="Reset" class="link" type="reset" style="margin: 20px;">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

input values will be submited. And this is not what you wanted.